# Angular Element with Angular Universal

Tags: angular

my app is an Angular Universal one and I have been trying to load a web component I created separately. I concatenated all js files for the child app into one and trying to use it in my parent app with the selector, however, the universal compilation is failing stating this:

```
Compiled successfully.
```

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'roles-permissions/roles-permissions.js'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'roles-permissions/roles-permissions.js'
at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:88305:16)
at CatchSubscriber.selector (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:88287:28)
at CatchSubscriber.error (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:165412:31)
at MapSubscriber._error (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:164435:26)
at MapSubscriber.error (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:164415:18)
at MapSubscriber._error (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:164435:26)
at MapSubscriber.error (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:164415:18)
at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber._error (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:164435:26)
at ThrowIfEmptySubscriber.error (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:164415:18)
at TakeLastSubscriber._error (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:164435:26)
at resolvePromise (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:173623:21)
at resolvePromise (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:173570:11)
at C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:173697:11
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:172664:173)
at Object.onInvokeTask (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:76390:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:172664:56)
at Zone.runTask (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:172416:39)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (C:\Projects\dev-portal-v2\dist\developer\server\main.js:172878:25)

my hosting component:

```
<roles-permissions></roles-permissions>
```

and how I am loading the script file:

```
export class AdminModule {
  constructor() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '../../../roles-permissions/roles-permissions.js';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }
}
```

Need a little help here.

Comment: The component is outside of your main project?

Comment: same root folder but yes, the 'src' and 'roles' folder are at the same level

Comment: And it work when you are developing with `ng serve` ?

Comment: since it is an Angular Universal, didnot try the 'ng serve' command

Comment: I have an Angular universal and i develop using `ng serve` normally, after it's done, i run the `ng build` normally

Comment: m confused somehow the '.js' file is not getting located by Angular.

GET http://localhost:4200/src/app/access/roles-permission/roles-permissions.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

solved this by following these steps:

1. remove routing module from your web component.
2. remove bootstrap from your web component.
3. keep the files in a good location, I changed it to 'assets' folder.

now working with 'ng serve' and 'npm run dev:ssr' too.